# Nifty Nines Impossibility Puzzle

Tags: calculation-puzzle

Could someone please provide me the solution to this puzzle:

99 + 9 = 9?

Professor Otto Doppelganger was one of Europe's leading puzzle experts. In the summer of 1899 he invented the Nifty Nines Impossibility. He proved that ninety nine plus nine is equal to nine if you add a certain five letter word to the equation.

That word was....?

Hint: It is added at the end of the equation.

Comment: I was struck by the fact that "Otto" is Italian for "eight". Which has no bearing on anything, it seems. Or perhaps this distinguished expert came up with more puzzles...

Answer (score 21):

I would propose:

> 99 + 9 = 9 dozen.